# Laravel authentication with encrypt password

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am attempting to log in using `Laravel` however I am having some issues

This is how i save my user:

```
$user = User::create(array('email'=> $_REQUEST['email'], 'password' => encrypt($password), 'firstname'=> $_REQUEST['firstname'], 'lastname'=>$_REQUEST['lastname'], 'unecrypted'=> $password));
```

Now as you can see i use `encrypt($password)` this created the following record in my database:

```
'39', 'myMail@mail.dk', 'eyJpdiI6Iis5RTRQdjBCV1piSVEwN0ZwRDQxa1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTnY1UnJ0YkVqZkY0VlhzdWhBK1QzUWxIdTc0SXNBRHlPcHQrcXpicmZHND0iLCJtYWMiOiJhODM2ZDI4ZTE5ZjY5YjlkNmQyOGIyYTdiOTU3NzFkNmNmZWNlOGVhMDNjYjY0ZTFiZjZiOGJlNWM3N2U4MmViIn0=', '2018-01-01 13:45:51', '2018-01-01 13:45:51', NULL, 'Marc', 'Rasmussen'
```

Which looks correct.

Then i have the following `LoginController`:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to login with my password (which I know is correct) I get the following message:

```
These credentials do not match our records.
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use "encrypt" for passwords, you should make a password hash https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`bcrypt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-bcrypt) helper to encrypt a password:

```
'password' => bcrypt($password),
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Laravel, but isn't it preferred to use the Hash facade? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing

Comment: @JimL Laravel uses `bcrypt()` by default to encrypt passwords. `bcrypt()` is just a shourtcut for `Hash::make()`.

Comment: Yes but when they change their mind and update to use a new hash algo then I assume the Hash facade will offer the same portability as the standard password lib.

Comment: @JimL they can also remove facade or rename the `make` method to something else etc. So, I wouldn't worry about that at all. )

Comment: True, it would mean they do something seriously wrong with the apis and interfaces they give laravel developers, but don't we all ^^ Sorry for dragging out the discussion, just a fan of latching on to abstractions/interfaces in tools I use as I expect them to survive - at least for quite a while :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own password encryption method you do not use laravel's built in Auth functionality Becuase laravel Auth match password only while the password encrypted through bcrypt method,
like `bcrypt($password);`

If you want to use you own encryption method you need to overwrite Auth login functionality and make own login logic.
I hope you understand what i want to say is.
Thank you.